# Connecting to wireless network on Boot Camp running Windows XP

Tags: windows-xp, mac, wireless-networking, boot-camp

I have a Mac Mini running a version of Windows XP on Boot Camp.

I'm trying to connect to a wireless network on the virtual machine using this guide:

> http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=czn5AmGVuoQ&feature=related

However I don't have a wireless network connection icon. What do I do?

Comment: We need more info to solve this issue.  What type of PC is it? Laptop, Desktop?  Is there for sure a wireless card? etc.

Comment: @KronoS It's a Mac Mini from last year, bootcamp. I can access the wireless network from OSX.

Answer (score 1):

After services and ncpa.cpl try clicking 'create a new connection'in the right pane of the network connections window, this should bring up an icon, it looks like her icon was an old connection and thus would have been there already,then carry on as shown. 
---sorry ben missunderstood.

Comment: Yes but there's nothing there that creates a wireless connection, only dial up stuff.

Comment: sorry missunderstood ben

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that the MAC has a valid connection to the internet you have to make sure that an installation of the drivers for the MAC on the Windows XP was installed.  This is done by following step three on this [pdf](http://manuals.info.apple.com/en/boot_camp_install-setup.pdf).  If this doesn't solve the issue a reinstall of the XP maybe needed.  This is the extent of my knowledge of MAC, but hope that this helps.

Comment: Well I can't find my mac cd, I need to get online to download the drivers.

Comment: Download the drivers on the mac, then share the files over to the virtual drive?